# get the dynamic button value with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

in asp.net mvc view page write this razor code for create the dynamic button:

```
  @foreach(var item in ViewBag.MenuLists)
        {
<button id="buttons" value=@item.RecordId >اضافه کردن به سبد خرید</button>

        }
```

and want to when button fire show the value for user for that purpose write this java script code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#buttons").click(function () {
                var fired_button = $("#buttons").val();
                alert(fired_button);
            });
        });
```

first dynamic button show the value,but when fire two or higher button dont show me alert,what happen?how can solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class to your buttons, with classes you can access click event for each button, like below code

```js
$(".btn").click(function()
{
alert("you clicked :"+ $(this).val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" value="1">1 </button>
<button class="btn" value="2">2 </button>
<button class="btn" value="3"> 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a handle on the `button` by `id`.  this is fine but new dynamic buttons dont have the same ID I assume, or shouldnt.  If they do you may only have an effect on the first of them [behavior not guaranteed].

another possibility is that since your buttons are loaded onto the `DOM` dynamically, they may not exist when the document is loaded and the `.ready()` function is called.  You will need to perhaps add a new bit of script for each button while putting it on the page, OR, develop some iterative naming technique for the `id` of each of them so they can be addressed independently.

in general `id` should be unique to the item while `classes` should be unique to similar items.  This is a guideline, not a rule, but there are practical reasons for it like `getElementByID()` compared to `getElementsByClass()`.

I think in your case however it is that new buttons are placed on the `DOM` after the initialization [`.click()`] has run.